# Installing ElasticSearch on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, elasticsearch

I'm trying to install ElasticSearch on a Linux environment. I'm almost there, but I'm doing something wrong.

Basically, my issue is this: when I run bin/elasticsearch in the terminal, I can access http://localhost.com:9200 just fine and run queries. But when I end the SSH session, I get a 404 when I try to hit http://localhost.com:9200 both in my browser window and through CURL.

This is the process I used to install ElasticSearch:

```
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.1.0.tar.gz

tar -zxvf elasticsearch-1.1.0.tar.gz

cd elasticsearch-1.1.0

bin/elasticsearch
```

Like I said, this works, and I can hit http://localhost.com:9200 to run queries, but only as long as the SSH session is active.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? I'm a novice at command line stuff, so I'm trying to feel my way through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 1.0 onwards the default option launches the service in foreground

[ElasticSearch Documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_system_and_settings.html) http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_system_and_settings.html

Try using the "-d"  option which runs the server as a daemon.